# Cannot install any app

Tags: software-installation

I am a new Elementary OS User, and I have a problem.

I could install apps before, but since I tried to install Spotify following [this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So5oy.png), I am getting an error message each time I try to install any app. Here's a picture of the error message:

[image]

Any way to fix this?

Thanks.

EDIT: The result of the cat command is two lines of text, and both say "sudo apt-get update".

Comment: Edit your question and paste the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list `  There must be something wrong inside that file..

Answer (score 1):

please can you give us more and better details:

- provide the link of the tutorial you followed (the link is a downsized image - thumbnail)
- open a terminal and write the following command and then show us what it says

  sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade
- again, open a terminal and write the following command and then show us what it says

  cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

it looks like you have a failed gimp installation and that image isn't showing us all what's happening
sometimes a previous faulty installation does not allow another one until it's fixed, but the image showed us that you have the command sudo in a sources.list file, that's wrong and you should fix that

you can install the latest spotify using snapd
https://snapcraft.io/spotify

--

> EDIT: The result of the cat command is two lines of text, and both say "sudo apt-get update".

Use this command, you did something wrong following the tutorial and the file is wrong

```
sudo rm -fr /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

If you want to install spotify, use snap
https://snapcraft.io/spotify
If you don't have it (snapd) follow the link
https://docs.snapcraft.io/core/install-elementary-os

Answer (score 0):

I'm nearly sure you didn't install Spotify correctly. At least that spotify.list file isn't correct so you need to remove it in order to install any other thing.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Then update your package list to make sure it works again:

```
sudo apt update
```